# convert timestamp to X second ago PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm currently developing an android app which retrieve data from SQL database using PHP. Every set of data got difference timestamp. The format of the timestamp in my database is (yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s). Now i want convert my timestamp so Android user will see the timestamp like (X second ago, X minutes ago or X days ago). I tried in my php code but result i get from the timestamp for every set of data is (1 days ago). every set of data show 1 days ago. Can anyone help me? thanks

**Product.php**

```
<?php

$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once 'include/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();


// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM image_detail ORDER BY posted_at DESC") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["products"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["uid"] = $row["uid"];
    $product["itemname"] = $row["itemname"];
    $product["price"] = $row["price"];
    $product["description"] = $row["description"];
    $product["path"] = $row["path"];
    $timestamp = $row["posted_at"];

    $now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    $product["posted_at"] = xTimeAgo($timestamp, $now, "x");




    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["products"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}

 function xTimeAgo ($oldTime, $newTime, $timeType) {
    $timeCalc = strtotime($newTime) - strtotime($oldTime);        
    if ($timeType == "x") {
        if ($timeCalc = 60) {
            $timeType = "m";
        }
        if ($timeCalc = (60*60)) {
            $timeType = "h";
        }
        if ($timeCalc = (60*60*24)) {
            $timeType = "d";
        }
    }        
    if ($timeType == "s") {
        $timeCalc .= " seconds ago";
    }
    if ($timeType == "m") {
        $timeCalc = round($timeCalc/60) . " minutes ago";
    }        
    if ($timeType == "h") {
        $timeCalc = round($timeCalc/60/60) . " hours ago";
    }
    if ($timeType == "d") {
        $timeCalc = round($timeCalc/60/60/24) . " days ago";
    }        
    return $timeCalc;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code always returns one day because of this block of code:

```
if ($timeType == "x") {
    if ($timeCalc = 60) {
        $timeType = "m";
    }
    if ($timeCalc = (60*60)) {
        $timeType = "h";
    }
    if ($timeCalc = (60*60*24)) {
        $timeType = "d";
    }
}
```

($timeCalc = 60) is not checking if $timeCalc is equal to 60, which is also wrong, it should check if it is greater than 60, it sets $timecalc to 60, which is also evaluated as true.

As a consequnce, every time you run the function, $timeCalc is first set to 60, then 60*60 and finally to 60*60*24. Likewise with $timeType, it is set to "m", then to "h" and finally to "d", and in this way, if you inspect your code, you see why it will always return one day.

Try setting the following if clauses instead:

```
if ($timeType == "x") {
    if ($timeCalc > 60) {
        $timeType = "m";
    }
    if ($timeCalc > (60*60)) {
        $timeType = "h";
    }
    if ($timeCalc > (60*60*24)) {
        $timeType = "d";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($timeType == "x") {
    if ($timeCalc = 60) {
        $timeType = "m";
    }
    if ($timeCalc = (60*60)) {
        $timeType = "h";
    }
    if ($timeCalc = (60*60*24)) {
        $timeType = "d";
    }
}
```

You've got a proble here,
you affect $timeCalc in your if:

```
$timeCalc = 60
```

For exemple, i think you just forget == in all if.

Corrected code :

```
if ($timeType == "x") {
    if ($timeCalc == 60) {
        $timeType = "m";
    }
    if ($timeCalc == (60*60)) {
        $timeType = "h";
    }
    if ($timeCalc == (60*60*24)) {
        $timeType = "d";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplified script for same will be

```
function xTimeAgo ($oldTime, $newTime) {
$timeCalc = strtotime($newTime) – strtotime($oldTime);
if ($timeCalc > (60*60*24)) {$timeCalc = round($timeCalc/60/60/24) . ” days ago”;}
else if ($timeCalc > (60*60)) {$timeCalc = round($timeCalc/60/60) . ” hours ago”;}
else if ($timeCalc > 60) {$timeCalc = round($timeCalc/60) . ” minutes ago”;}
else if ($timeCalc > 0) {$timeCalc .= ” seconds ago”;}
return $timeCalc;
}
```

Try this. Hope this will help you.

There is a good example of [code](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-calculate-real-differences-between-two-dates-or-timestamps/)